# Amazon S3 waitFor() inside AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm having issue when calling `S3.waitFor()` function from inside Lambda function (Serverless nodejs). I'm trying to asynchronously write a file into Amazon S3 using `S3.putObject()` from one rest api, and poll the result file from another rest api using `S3.waitFor()` to see if the writing is ready/finished.

Please see the following snippet:

```
...
S3.waitFor('objectExists', {
  Bucket: bucketName,
  Key: fileName,
  $waiter: {
    maxAttempts: 5,
    delay: 3
  }
}, (error, data) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log("error:" + JSON.stringify(error))
  } else {
    console.log("Success")
  }
});
...
```

Given **valid** bucketName and **invalid** fileName, when the code runs in my local test script, it returns error after 15secs (3secs x 5 retries) and generates result as follows:

```
error: {
  "message": "Resource is not in the state objectExists",
  "code": "ResourceNotReady",
  "region": null,
  "time": "2018-08-03T06:08:12.276Z",
  "requestId": "AD621033DCEA7670",
  "extendedRequestId": "JNkxddWX3IZfauJJ63SgVwyv5nShQ+Mworb8pgCmb1f/cQbTu3+52aFuEi8XGro72mJ4ik6ZMGA=",
  "retryable": true,
  "statusCode": 404,
  "retryDelay": 3000
}
```

Meanwhile, when it is running inside AWS lambda function, it returns result directly as follows:

```
error: {
  "message": "Resource is not in the state objectExists",
  "code": "ResourceNotReady",
  "region": null,
  "time": "2018-08-03T05:49:43.178Z",
  "requestId": "E34D731777472663",
  "extendedRequestId": "ONMGnQkd14gvCfE/FWk54uYRG6Uas/hvV6OYeiax5BTOCVwbxGGvmHxMlOHuHPzxL5gZOahPUGM=",
  "retryable": false,
  "statusCode": 403,
  "retryDelay": 3000
}
```

As you can see that the retryable and statusCode values are different between the two.

On lamba, it seems that it always get statusCode 403 when the file doesn't exists. While on my local, everything works as expected (retried 5 times every 3 seconds and received statusCode 404).

I wonder if it has anything to do with IAM role. Here's my IAM role statements settings inside my serverless.yml:

```
iamRoleStatements:
- Effect: "Allow"
 Action:
   - "logs:CreateLogGroup"
   - "logs:CreateLogStream"
   - "logs:PutLogEvents"
   - "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface"
   - "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces"
   - "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"
   - "sns:Publish"
   - "sns:Subscribe"
   - "s3:*"
 Resource: "*"
```

How to make it work from lambda function?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are your bucket and lambda function in the same region?

Comment: @MikePatrick Yes it's in the same region.
By the way, I've found the solution for this issue. It's related with S3.headObject() function. I'm posting the solution soon. 

Thanks for the efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the key is on how you set the IAM Role for the bucket and all the objects under it.

Based on the AWS docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#waitFor-property), it states that `S3.waitFor()` is relying on the underlying `S3.headObject()`.

> Waits for the objectExists state by periodically calling the underlying **S3.headObject()** operation every 5 seconds (at most 20 times).

Meanwhile, `S3.headObject()` itself relies on HEAD Object API which has the following rule as stated on AWS Docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html#RESTObjectHEAD_Description):

> You need the **s3:GetObject** permission for this operation.  For more information, go to Specifying Permissions in a Policy in the Amazon Simple Storage Service Developer Guide. **If the object you request does not exist, the error Amazon S3 returns depends on whether you also have the s3:ListBucket permission**.
>
> - **If you have the s3:ListBucket** permission on the bucket, Amazon S3
>     will return a HTTP status code **404 ("no such key")** error.
> - **if you don’t have the s3:ListBucket** permission, Amazon S3 will return
>     a HTTP status code **403 ("access denied")** error.

It means that I need to add `s3:ListBucket` Action to the Bucket resource containing the objects to be able to get response 404 when the objects doesn't exist.

Therefore, I've configured the cloudformation AWS::IAM::Policy resource as below, where I added `s3:Get*` and `s3:List*` action specifically on the Bucket itself (i.e.: S3FileStorageBucket).

```
    "IamPolicyLambdaExecution": {
        "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
        "DependsOn": [
            "IamRoleLambdaExecution",
            "S3FileStorageBucket"
        ],
        "Properties": {
            "PolicyName": { "Fn::Join": ["-", ["Live-RolePolicy", { "Ref": "environment"}]]},
            "PolicyDocument": {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Effect":"Allow",
                        "Action": [
                            "s3:Get*",
                            "s3:List*"
                        ],
                        "Resource": {
                            "Fn::Join": [
                                "",
                                [
                                    "arn:aws:s3:::",
                                    {
                                        "Ref": "S3FileStorageBucket"
                                    }
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Effect":"Allow",
                        "Action": [
                            "s3:GetObject",
                            "s3:PutObject",
                            "s3:DeleteObject"
                        ],
                        "Resource": {
                            "Fn::Join": [
                                "",
                                [
                                    "arn:aws:s3:::",
                                    {
                                        "Ref": "S3FileStorageBucket"
                                    },
                                    "/*"
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    ...
```

Now I've been able to do `S3.waitFor()` to poll for file/object under the bucket with only a single API call and get the result only when it's ready, or throw error when the resource is not ready after a specific timeout.

That way, the client implementation will be much simpler. As it doesn't have to implement poll by itself.

Hope that someone find it usefull. Thank you.

Comment: Also, you can play around with the polling period by passing undocumented `$waiter` property on the second argument of `S3.waitFor()` above.